# Hide readonly field on form if its value is None

Tags: python, django

I have typical django model form and I want to hide one readonly field if its value is None and show if it has any value. Also this field is declared in Admin class, not on form.

```
class DjangoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   from = DjangoForm
   readonly_fields = ("my_field",)

   fieldsets = (
      ("Title", {
      "fields": ("my_field",)
      }
    )
   )
   def get_my_field():
      value = None
      if ...:
         value = 1
      return value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply filter in get_queryset as below...

```
class DjangoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    --- your code and logic ---
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).exclude(my_field=None)
```

Now, you will only get those data in which my_field value is not a None. :)

Comment: It will not hide the field if its value == ""

Comment: It means you want that if value == None then the full row will be hidden, right?

Comment: Edited my answer, just check it.

Comment: My field is populated in admin class. I don't have it in database

Comment: Then based on which field value, you want to hide and show that field?

Comment: On a value from a queryset